# How to migrate OAuth out-of-band to a safer alternative

Tags: oauth

I recently got an email that one of my Google Cloud applications which is only used by myself must be migrated from OAuth OOB flow to a safer alternative
The only usage for this application is to publish Chrome extensions using the [Chrome Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/api_index/) via a local file with my account's credentials

How do I migrate it?

Answer (score 1):

I got this too, for a Desktop application built very recently using Google's own examples and documentation.

If yours is a single user application, I would guess it is still in test mode (i.e. unverified) in which case what I've read about OOB states that applications in test mode won't be affected. However in two different places Google say that the effective cutoff date is August and another says it is in October, so they don't really seem to have a grip on what they are doing.